# If $y\equiv 1 mod 4$ then $y^2 \equiv 1 mod 8$

Tags: congruences

Given $$
y\equiv 1\  mod \ 4
$$
How can i proove that
$$
y^2\equiv1\ mod\ 8
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $y=4k + 1$ hence $y^2 = 16k^2 + 8k + 1$